# Как установить по умолчанию в maven версию компилятора jdk?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Как сменить версию компилятора на 1.8 по умолчанию, когда я создаю какой-либо архитип через maven. Или мне придется каждый раз в POM файле  в properties указывать

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

В настоящий момент я получаю ошибку, если не укажу вышестоящий код:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project unit-test: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] Source option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: даже если сможете изменить у себя по дефолту, на других машинах дефолтная останется. Это может вылезти при сборке. Думаю тут проще в идее шаблон создать, сразу с нужными параметрами

Comment: А это нормальная практика в общем то и как это сделать( создать шаблон в идее)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас на комьютере устновлен мавен, тогда зайдите в папку с мавеном и добавьте новый профаил в  **conf/settings.xml**

```
<profile>
            <id>default</id>
                <properties>
                    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
                    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
                </properties>
</profile>
```

Теперь, когда создадите проект в идее, поставьте галочку, напротив default в разделе "maven".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]